# Add Unknown Old Printer to Linux OS

Tags: manjaro, printer

I found a very old never used printer "Canon Cp-220" and i wanna use it with my Manjaro distribution

i found out that i need the "Gutenprint" driver collection , i have installed that distribution specific package.

now i wanted to know how actually i am adding the printer to my operating system,

**EDIT**

After some research about the cups stuff, i installed the necessary cups package for my dist. (manjaro-printer), in the gui i try to add the printer , i finally see the right printer model on the list , it says searching for driver, then i guess it found it and then it says " cups operation error - 'client-error-not-possible'

after reading the dist. specific printing wiki page (https://wiki.manjaro.org/index.php?title=Printing)
i did

```
sudo systemctl enable --now org.cups.cupsd.service
```

and finally i was able to add the printer and it worked , yay

thanks anyway

Comment: Have you tried the obvious "Add printer" in your GUI? What happened?

Comment: after some research about the cups stuff, i installed the necessary cups package for my dist. (system-config-printer), in the gui i try to add the printer , i finally see the right printer model on the list , it says searching for driver, then i guess it found it and then it says " cups operation error - 'client-error-not-possible'

Comment: That's helpful. Please [add it to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/544833/edit) so all the relevant information is in one place. If you've got anything else to add, do that too, please. Make it easy for people to read and understand your issue.

Comment: @synq1 You have an answer! Suggest you post it as an answer, then come back and click the checkmark to show it solved your problem. so other folks benefit from your experience.